# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

English Language Learners' [second moderator election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: snailplane]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/flair/230.png))</sub>
[image: ColleenV]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6344763229863936/0).

Comment: Excellent news :)

Comment: Congratulations, you two! I know you'll do an excellent job moderating with the team!

Comment: Congrats to Snailplane and Colleen! I wanted a mod from chat, so I won anyway!

Comment: Congratulatons to both!

Comment: @HowardPautz Just for the record, that's *she* and *her* :-)

Comment: Congratulations, to you guys! :)

Comment: Jolly good show.  Well done to the worthy winners.

Comment: Voila! @snailplane, I've voted for you. Congratulation to you.

Comment: @snailplane Congratulations to you both. And especially to snailplane, who, when she was merely a snailboat was always kind, courteous, and helpful. Now that she's gained her moderator wings and become a snailplane, may she _ _ _ _ ... well you can guess that metaphor ... :))  [Edit - I have no clue why I thought you were a he :)) thanks for the correction !]

Comment: Two active members, two knowledgeable ELL users, two amicable people...welcome to the mods' world! :)